# Performance of the Toronto Paper Matching System (TPMS) for (conference) paper review assignment

Tags: peer-review, conference, computer-science, learning

[EDIT (2016-11-11) based on a comment]

I have been invited as a reviewer for the IEEE International Conference on Image Processing  ([ICIP 2016](http://2016.ieeeicip.org/), on image processing, in a broad domain sometimes associated to computer science). The ancient system was based on ticked keywords (by benevolent reviewers) in a list (and on the area chairs' expertise).

The novel system is called TPMS. It is based on the paper [Toronto Paper Matching System: An automated paper-reviewer assignment system](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~lcharlin/papers/tpms.pdf). It uses a [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) ("statistical matching") technique based on a sample of the reviewer's publications. It has also been used for [CVPR 2016](http://cvpr2016.thecvf.com/organizers/chairs_message) (Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition conference).

- Has the TPMS system   been successfully deployed?
- Do reviewers or editors have a quantitative evaluation  of the efficiency of such systems?

Comment: a request for feedback is not a question that can be answered. maybe you could instead ask whether the TPMS system has been successfully deployed.

Comment: Nice suggestion

Answer (score 6):

Laurent Charlin's reference (http://papermatching.cs.toronto.edu/webapp/profileBrowser/about_us/) suggests that it's been adopted by "over 50 conferences", including the following conferences:

- European Conference on Computer Vision
- Conference on Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence
- Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems
- Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition
- International Conference on Computer Vision
- International Conference on Machine Learning
- Artificial Intelligence and Statistics Conference

And it also "keeps the profiles of 8,000 reviewers". In machine learning circles, this is just about as good as it gets with non-mass-market data. The size of the training pool and the fact that it's been continuously worked on means it is likely to have become a fairly reliable tool.